# One drive cycling status icons on desktop

Tags: windows-11, onedrive, desktop-icons

I have an intermittent issue with OneDrive on Windows 11.

On my desktop, the OneDrive status icons (i.e. green-tick, red-cross) which show on top of file thumbnails start cycling through different images; where the green tick should be, I might get the icon for Excel then Adobe-reader and Recycle bin, etc.
(Next time it happens I will try to get some pictures of this).

It doesn't seem to have any adverse affect on the computer, it's just irritating as the icons change 1-2 times per second.

Any idea why?

Comment: Does this issue go away if you perform a reboot?

Comment: @Ramhound, it does. But will start again in a few days.

Comment: I noticed some odd behavior on my own machine, I had green checkmarks on my own desktop icons, the difference is that I do NOT syncrhonize my desktop to OneDrive. So my current thought is you had a pending Windows Update, since when I rebooted my own machine, there was a pending update.  What other programs like OneDrive do you have installed on your system?

Comment: Thanks for the info @Ramhound. Windows updates are controlled by my companies IT department, so I'll have to bring my laptop in to them for a checkup. 
I don't any other applications like OneDrive on my computer.